# How do I specifically use \n for the print function?

Tags: python, printing, newline

```
a = int(input("Enter a number: "))
print("The next number for the number", a, "is", a+1)
print("The previous number for the number", a, "is", a-1)
```

I'd like to use just one-line command with the print function, in which I say to print in 2 lines. I'v tried the following code, but it doesn't work properly, because it prints the second line after a space. I'd like to remove this useless space.

```
print("The next number for the number", a, "is", a+1,"\n","The previous number for the number", a, "is", a-1)
```

Comment: How does it "not working properly"?

Comment: Don’t separate the line break from the next string… `"\nThe previous ..."`

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
print("The next number for the number %i \nThe next number for the number %i" % (int(a)+1, int(a)-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to concatenate the \n separately.  It will create a newline anywhere in a string:

print("The next number for the number", a, "is", a+1,"\nThe previous number for the number", a, "is", a-1)

The next number for the number 3 is 4 
The previous number for the number 3 is 2